# How do I install the latest npm version on my shared server through SSH

Tags: node.js, linux

I have been trying to update the npm on the shared hosting server (linux) through SSH using this command: npm i npm@latest -g

I keep getting this error message:

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-714.10.2.lve1.4.66.el6h.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "i" "npm@latest" "-g"
npm ERR! node v0.10.47
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.3
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/abbrev
npm ERR! code EACCES

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, access '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/abbrev'
npm ERR!     at module.exports (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/access-error.js:4:18)
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/writable.js:30:25
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:232:16
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, access '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/abbrev']
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/abbrev' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

I have tried to follow this advice,

```
chown -R $USER /usr/local
```

but no success.

Any advice is welcome

Comment: Read the error. **ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.** Maybe use `sudo`?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thanks jww, I got it solved but in future, only programming questions here